# How can I run the filter function only when the searchbar text is not empty?

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement, vector, swiftui

I have a search button and a search bar in SwiftUi View.
i'm try to run the function filter() when the user type in the Searchbar.

If I use the button to trig the action it works, but I want to trig the action when user typing in the bar.

I have tried with if else but give me a warning.

Generic parameter 'FalseContent' could not be inferred
1. In call to function 'buildEither(first:)' (SwiftUI.ViewBuilder)

here my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dm: DataManager
    @State private var searchTerm : String = ""
    @State var filteredAirports: [AirportModel] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)
            if searchTerm == "" {
                /// don't do anything 
            } else {
                self.dm.filter2(valoreSearhed: self.searchTerm, arrayTosearh: self.dm.airportVector)
            }

            List {
                ForEach(dm.appoggio) { valore in
                    Text(valore.aptICAO)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not your if/else because this works:

as you can see, the if/else is in there and no compiler warning...
Tipp: try to comment out all statements and then iterate by uncommenting and check when compiler warns you -> then you have your error

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var list = ["1","2","3"]
    @State private var searchTerm : String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
       //     SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)
            if searchTerm == "" {
                /// don't do anything
            } else {
//                self.dm.filter2(valoreSearhed: self.searchTerm, arrayTosearh: self.dm.airportVector)
            }

            List(list, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
//                ForEach(dm.appoggio) { valore in
//                    Text(valore.aptICAO)
//                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a custom `Binding` that executes the filtering when the `searchTerm` changes:

```swift
    SearchBar(text: $searchTerm.didSet(execute: { _ in self.updateSearchResults() }))

...

extension Binding {
    /// Execute block when value is changed.
    ///
    /// Example:
    ///
    ///     Slider(value: $amount.didSet { print($0) }, in: 0...10)
    func didSet(execute: @escaping (Value) ->Void) -> Binding {
        return Binding(
            get: {
                return self.wrappedValue
            },
            set: {
                self.wrappedValue = $0
                execute($0)
            }
        )
    }
}
```